# PrimeNG resets the value passed to NgRx store

Tags: angular, frontend, ngrx, primeng

I'm encountering the issue with - probably - PrimeNG p-dropdown and the NgRx store. In my service I pass the data to be saved inside the store:

```
 this.store.dispatch(new SetValueAction(initialMyFormState.controls.someId.id, myObj.id))
```

Inside my component:

```
<ims-select
      [formControlState]="(formState$ | async).controls.someId"
      ...
    >
    </ims-select>
```

ims-select component:

```
<div #dropdownContainer>
  <p-dropdown
    #dropdown
    [styleClass]="'p-dropdown-overwrite'"
    [ngrxFormControlState]="formControlState"
    ...
  >
  
  </p-dropdown>
</div>
```

The problem is that, when I trigger the dispatch action in the service, my NgRx store performs two events:

1. Correctly sets the id to the store
2. Sets the null value almost instantly

I've tried to debug it for a while now, but nothing seems to help, also it's working in a very non-logical manner, so I suspect it may be some sort of conflict between PrimeNG and NgRx.
Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you provide the code of `SetValueAction` reducer and also .ts code where you assign the value to `formControlState` variable within the component?